# switched primary on Mongo replica set. now I can't admin it

Tags: mongodb

I have three servers in a freshly created replica set. let's say they are sv1, sv2, sv3. sv1 is the primary.

In sv1, I created a root user and authenticated myself with it. then I did rs.stepDown() because sv1 was actually the furthest machine in the replica set and I wanted a primary a bit closer to the rest of my network.

I then went into sv2, which was the new primary, and did rs.status(). It complained that I don't have admin rights.

```
not authorized on admin to execute command { replSetGetStatus: 1.0 }
```

I tried to create a root user on that server (use admin; db.createUser(...) ), but can't do so because I apparently don't have rights...

```
Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on admin to execute command
```

and when I try authenticating with the user I created on the sv1 machine, it of course fails:

```
sv2:PRIMARY> db.auth('root','[PASS]');
Error: 18 Authentication failed.
```

Any idea what I should do to regain control? I can't make sv1 primary now, because only the primary server can do that (as far as I know), but I can't authenticate on sv2...

Answer (score 1):

it seems that after a user creation from another node, you must exit the other servers and log in to them again, this time using user auth details from the console.

Example:

```
sv:PRIMARY> use admin
switched to db admin
sv:PRIMARY> db.auth('root','[PASS]');
Error: 18 Authentication failed.
0
sv:PRIMARY> exit
bye
```

and immediately afterwards, I log in, using the exact same password that failed above...

```
[root@sv2 ~]# mongo admin -uroot -p
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.12
Enter password: 
connecting to: admin
sv:PRIMARY>
```

After this, commands such as rs.status(), etc, will work as normal.